# Settings.Secure - LOCATION_MODE deprecated - alternative for writing

Tags: android, android-location

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_MODE) the flag `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` has been depreacted in API 28. Is there an alternative way to **write** this setting? (I'm not interested in reading this value, which can be done via `LocationManager`)

The following works on my android pie device:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF)
Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY)
```

Is it possible to get this exact same result when targetting > API 28 devices?.

Answer (score 5):

I use this method to check if location service enabled or not

```
   public static Boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            // This is new method provided in API 28
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            return lm.isLocationEnabled();
        } else {
            // This is Deprecated in API 28
            int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
                    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
            return (mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
        }
    }
```

**Edit :**
I misinterpreted the question here's how i do it to change location settings

```
/**
 * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
 */
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000;
/**
 * The fastest rate for active location updates. Updates will never be more frequent
 * than this value.
 */
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
/**
 * Small displacement for location updates
 */
private static final int SHORTEST_DISTANCE_IN_METER = 5;

ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> intentSenderForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
        , result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {

            } else {

            }
        });

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest(){
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SHORTEST_DISTANCE_IN_METER);
        return locationRequest;

}

  

private void changeLocationSettings(){
      //Ask to turn on location setting if not enabled
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(requireContext());
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
            task.addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> {
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.

            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(resolvable.getResolution()).build();
                    intentSenderForResult.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: The snippet you provided checks whether location services are on. The question is about changing location services state, which is a much more restricted operation